# list subdirectories recursively

Tags: bash, shell

I want to write a shell script so as to recursively list all different subdirectories which contain NEW subdirectory (NEW is a fixed name).

```
Dir1/Subdir1/Subsub1/NEW/1.jpg
Dir1/Subdir1/Subsub1/NEW/2.jpg
Dir1/Subdir1/Subsub2/NEW/3.jpg
Dir1/Subdir1/Subsub2/NEW/4.jpg
Dir1/Subdir2/Subsub3/NEW/5.jpg
Dir1/Subdir2/Subsub4/NEW/6.jpg
```

I want to get

```
Dir1/Subdir1/Subsub1
Dir1/Subdir1/Subsub2
Dir1/Subdir2/Subsub3 
Dir1/Subdir2/Subsub4
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.   For example, why do you not want to show `Dir1/Subdir1/Subsub1/NEW`?    In any case do a man on `find`, which will likely do what you want...

Comment: Actually, I want to find all different addresses for my NEW subdirectories.

Comment: Yes, noticed your edit.   You want to use `find` to find all directories named `NEW`, and then use `sed` to remove the trailing `/NEW`s...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -type d -name NEW | sed 's|/NEW$||'
```

--- EDIT ---

for your comment, sed does not have a -print0.   There are various ways of doing this (most of which are wrong).   One possible solution would be:

```
find . -type d -name NEW -print0 | \
  while IFS= read -rd '' subdirNew; do \
          subdir=$(sed 's|/NEW$||' <<< "$subdirNew"); \
          echo "$subdir"; \
  done
```

which should be tolerant of spaces and newlines in the filename

Comment: Thanks. But why is this code not working? find . -type d -name NEW | sed 's|/NEW$||' -print0 | while IFS= read -rd '' dir; do echo "$dir"; done

Comment: `-print0` is an option to `find`, not `sed`.   To use that with `sed`, you need to use `sed -z`.  That's only supported in sed 4.2.2 and later.    I'll edit my answer with a possible workaround

Answer (score 1):

`ls -R` will list things recursively.

of `find . | grep "/NEW/"` should give you the type of list you are looking for.

Comment: HardcoreHenry's answer is probably more accurate.  This approach only gives you the list of candidates, not the output list that is being asked for.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
find . -type d -name "NEW" -exec dirname {} \;
```